# Make overflow content scroll within div

Tags: html, css

If you look at the snippet below, you will see text within a div with an image. I'm trying to make it so that when I scroll, the content in the image div will scroll while having the image at a fixed height.

At the moment the div itself is moving, however, I would like the text to scroll instead.

Once the content inside this div has finished scrolling, I would like the page to scroll to the next `blue` div.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.box .content {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#red {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512389142860-9c449e58a543?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="red">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
      elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
      dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
      dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
      occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
      qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="blue">
</div>
```

I've tried to add:

```
.content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

However, this doesn't achieve exactly what I want. The issue with this is that it adds a scroll bar to the right of the content, and the content only scrolls when it is focused. Lastly, it doesn't scroll down to the next `blue` div once the text has finished scrolling.

Is there anyway to achieve this using CSS? Perhaps with `position: sticky` maybe?

Comment: it seems you are looking for the trivial and initial behavior .. if you remove height contraint you will scroll the red div until this one is done then you will get the blue one like you want

Comment: @TemaniAfif If you picture an image instead of the `red` div, then this image will stretch to fill the height of the content (thus having the image as a background of the entire content). Would there be a way to make this have a particular height (so the image has a fixed height) and so the text scrolls ontop of the image/div?

Comment: yes, play with background position/size and consider background-attachement:fixed. If the image is your problem then we are having an XY problem, you are describing your problem in a bad way leading us to think about something non trivial

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, sorry. I've had a hard time wording this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjust the background properties like below to have your image fixed while scrolling:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box .content {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

#red {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512389142860-9c449e58a543?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb");
  background-size: 100% 100vh; /* make the height 100vh */
  background-attachment:fixed; /* this will do the magic */
}

#blue {
  background: blue;
  min-height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="red">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
      elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
      dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
      dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
      occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
      qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="blue">
</div>
```

You can also have a different effect using sticky and pseudo element:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.box .content {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-top:-100vh;
}

#red::before {
  content:"";
  position:sticky;
  display:block;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:100vh;
  z-index:-1;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512389142860-9c449e58a543?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#blue {
  background: blue;
  min-height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="red">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
      elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
      dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
      dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
      occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
      qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="blue">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the trick. Cheers for the quick answer

Comment: @NickParsons I added another way to have a different effect

Comment: Awesome, that looks great! Thanks so much again for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `overflow-y: scroll;` to .box and remove it from .content:

```
.box {
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100%;
   overflow-y:scroll;
 }
```